# Making a Value of an Encrypted Field Unique

Tags: mysql, jpa, encryption, jasypt

A JavaEE application uses Jasypt simple encryptor to encrypt usernames stored in a MySQL database using JPA.

As the usernames are encrypted, can't make the username column unique. (Refer to use cases below.)

A search can be performed before saving a new username to avoid duplicates, but there is a theoretical possibility of creating multiple users names simultaneously.

```
Encrypt('username','key') = 'EncryptedUsername'

Decrypt('EncryptedUsername','key') = 'username'
```

Case 1 - Already in the database

- Username1 = 'a'
- Key1 = '1'
- EncryptedValue1 = 'XXXX' (suppose)

Case 2 - Going to add a new username

- Username2 = 'b'
- Key2 = '2'
- EncryptedValue2 = 'XXXX' (suppose)

Case 3 - Going to add another new username

- Username3 = 'a'
- Key3 = '3'
- EncryptedValue3 = 'YYYY' (suppose)

Case 2 must be allowed.

case 3 must not be allowed

I can not achieve that by making the field I store the encrypted value unique.

If I make it unique, it will not allow adding new username 'b' in case 2. That is wrong as existing username 'a' is different from the new username 'b'.

In case 3, it will also allow adding the 'a' as a username as the encrypted values are different.

How can we make sure the user name remains unique despite encryption?

Comment: Why can't it be unique?

Comment: I use different keys to encrypt different usernames. Hence, I thought when encrypting, there is a possibility to have the same encrypted value for two different user names. If that is not so, the problem is solved.

Comment: When `encrypt('a') = 'x'` and `encrypt('b') = 'x'` - what would be `decrypt('x')`?

Comment: When encrypt('a', 'key1') = 'x' and encrypt('b', 'key2') = 'x'  then decrypt('x','key1')='a' and decrypt('x','key2')='b'

Comment: @BuddhikaAriyaratne: Then the usernames themselves are not unique (a and b)... And the chance of both here resulting in an encrypted 'x' is next to none... My impression of your question was: When `encrypt('a', 'key1') = 'x'` and `encrypt('a', 'key2') = 'y'`, how can I prevent a to be used twice since in the db the entries are unique

Comment: But where are the keys stored? And how would you perform a duplicate check as you write "*A search can be performed before saving a new username to avoid duplicates*"?

Comment: I use the id of the MySQL row as the key. But it may change. Still, the concept is been developed.

Comment: "*I use the id of the MySQL row as the key*" - That's "interesting". Sounds like obfuscation rather than encryption.

Comment: Don't... bad design... finding duplictes becomes very expensive with the increase of users.

Comment: Username1 'a'
Key '1'
Encrypted value 1 'XXXX' (suppose)

Username1 'b'
Key '2'
Encrypted value 'XXXX' (suppose)

If I make the Encrypted value column unique, it will not allow adding new username 'b'. I need to avoid that.

Comment: Then is it ok to have usernames unencrypted in the database?

Comment: I planed to store the 2nd, 4th and 7th characters of the username in three fields and decrypt only the matched records. So the performance will be not an issue.

Comment: Username1 = 'a',    
Key1 = '1',    
EncryptedValue1 = 'XXXX' (suppose);    

Username2 = 'b'
Key2 = '2'
EncryptedValue2 =  'XXXX' (suppose)

If I make the Encrypted value column unique, it will not allow adding new username 'b'. I need to avoid that.

Comment: Then don't make the column unique (it does in this examle say nothing about uniqueness of the username, so it is useless) Why are you 'scared' of storing usernames clear text or hashed with  fixed salt?

Comment: Or a non-fixed salt

Comment: I have added use cases to the question. This is for a medical application where almost all the fields are going to be encrypted. Even if some unwanted authority got hold of the database, he must not be able to get useful data.

Comment: Then do database level encryption...

Comment: Or hash with an obscured salt...

Comment: Database level encryption is ideal, but difficult to afford for MySQL Enterprise Encryption. (It is not available in community edition.). If you add that as the answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Use an application scope bean to search for the provided username. If the new username is not found, create a user with the new username. If the username found, ask for another one from the user. As there is only one place to carry out this function, there will be no duplicates.