# Preventing insertion of duplicates without using indices

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table `users` that looks roughly like this:

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
email_hash INT, -- indexed
encrypted_email TEXT,
other_stuff JSON
```

For privacy reasons, I cannot store actual emails in the database.

The encryption used for emails is not 1-to-1, i.e. one email can be encrypted to many different encrypted representations. This makes it pointless to just slap an index on the `encrypted_email` column, as it will never catch a duplicate.

There are already data in the database and changing the encryption method or the hashing method is out of question.

The `email_hash` column cannot have a unique index either, as it is supposed to be a short hash to just speed up duplicate checks. It cannot be too unique, as it would void all privacy guarantees.

How can I prevent two entries with the same email from appearing in the database?

Another limitation: I probably cannot use `LOCK TABLE`, as according to the documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lock-tables/

> `LOCK TABLES` doesn't work when using Galera cluster. You may experience crashes or locks when used with Galera.
>
> `LOCK TABLES` implicitly commits the active transaction, if any. Also, starting a transaction always releases all table locks acquired with `LOCK TABLES`.

(I do use Galera and I do need transactions as inserting a new user is accompanied with several other inserts and updates)

---

Since the backend application server (a monolith) is allowed to handle personal information (for example for sending email messages, verifying logins etc.) as long as it doesn't store it, I do the duplicate check in the application.

Currently, I'm doing something like this (pseudocode):

```
perform "START TRANSACTION"
h := hash(new_user.email)
conflicts := perform "SELECT encrypted_email FROM users WHERE email_hash = ?", h
for conflict in conflicts :
    if decrypt(conflict) == new_user.email :
        perform "ROLLBACK"
        return DUPLICATE
e := encrypt(new_user.email)
s := new_user.other_stuff
perform "INSERT INTO users (email_hash, encrypted_email, other_stuff) VALUES (?,?,?)", h, e, s
perform some other inserts as part of the transaction
perform "COMMIT"
return OK
```

which works fine if two attempts are separated in time. However, when two threads try to add the same user simultaneously, then both transactions run in parallel, do the select, see no conflicting duplicate, and then both proceed to add the user. How to prevent that, or at least gracefully immediately recover?

---

This is how the race looks like, simplified:

- Two threads start their transactions
- Both threads do the select and the select returns zero rows in both cases.
- Both threads assume there won't be a duplicate.
- Both threads add the user.
- Both threads commit the transactions.
- There are now two users with the same email.

Comment: is there anything in `other stuff` that might help uniquely identify an individual (even if they can only pull it down to a handful of matches and not completely uniquely identify them)?  My thoughts are is if that's viable, you could check against all of the matches....

Comment: @user2366842 There is not. As for "pull it down to a handful of matches", that's what the hash is for.

Comment: "one email can be encrypted to many different encrypted representations" -- Perhaps you meant the opposite?

Comment: @RickJames No. What I meant is that each email can be encrypted with different initialization vectors and even different keys, so I cannot detect duplicate emails comparing just encrypted data.

Comment: It sounds like you have made it impossible to _decrypt_.  As others have said, a one-way hash may be a better approach to dedupping.

Comment: Related question: [Making a Value of an Encrypted Field Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833606/making-a-value-of-an-encrypted-field-unique) - And the same question here: Where are the keys stored? You need some kind of "in-app-db" for the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tack `FOR UPDATE` on the end of the `SELECT`.

Also, since you are using Galera, you must check for errors after `COMMIT`.  (That is when conflicts with the other nodes are reported.)

Comment: How is FOR UPDATE supposed to help? Two concurrent transactions won't lock any rows, because the other transaction hasn't added its new entry yet.

Comment: @KarolS - `FOR UPDATE`, in this case, announces the possibility of inserting a row in that area.

Comment: @KarolS - `select email_hash from users where email_hash = 123 limit 1 for update;` locks the second connection from doing the same until the first connection commits. Even when the table was empty. Tested on MariaDB 10.3.13.

Comment: (Presumably, that has _always_ been the case in InnoDB.)

Comment: Okay, so I just tested this and it appears to work correctly. Thanks. I didn't knew FOR UPDATE works like that.

Answer (score 3):

Your pseudocode risks race conditions unless you can force the code to run serially. That is, only one request at a time can attempt to insert an email. The whole block of code you show in your pseudocode has to be in a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).

If you can't use LOCK TABLES you could try [MariaDB's GET_LOCK() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/get_lock/). I'm not sure if that's compatible with Galera, that's something for you to research.

If that's not possible, you'll have to find some other method of forcing that block of code to run serially. You haven't described your programming language or your application deployment architecture. Maybe you could use some kind of [distributed lock server in Redis](https://redis.io/topics/distlock) or something like that.

But even if you can accomplish this, making the code run serially, that will probably create a bottleneck in your app. Only one thread at a time will be able to insert a new email, and you'll probably find that they queue up waiting for the global lock.

Sorry, but that is the consequence of the constraints of this system, since you cannot implement it with a unique key, which would be the proper way to do it.

Good luck.

Comment: I concur with this answer. Given the constraints outlined by OP, there is no way for MySQL/MariaDB to enforce uniqueness. +10

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You can't.  You have one field where one email gets multiple values.  That's of no use for identifying duplicate values.

You have another field where multiple emails have the same value.  That just raises false errors on duplicates.

If you want to prevent duplicates, then I would suggest a more robust hashing mechanism that greatly reduces collisions so you can use that.  Otherwise, you need to do the validation behind a PII wall.

Comment: "Otherwise, you need to do the validation behind a PII wall." Yes, that's what I'm doing currently, but it doesn't work well. I do not expect a pure SQL solution. Any hint how to make it work?

Comment: @KarolS . . . Use a different hashing function that is less prone to collisions.  A four-byte hash result is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Also too long for a comment:

To prevent duplicate entries in a table you should use an unique index, so MariaDB will be able to detect duplicates.

A 4 byte hash/checksum (`INT`) is not unique enough and might have too many collisions. Instead of checksum, you should store the encrypted password (e.g. encrypting it by using AES-256-CTR or any other block cipher) in the table, the key and iv (initialization vector) should be stored on the client. Each encrypted value will now be unique, and for security encrypted value and key/iv are stored in different locations.

```
/* Don't send plain password, e.g. by using MariaDB's aes_encryot function
   we encrypt it already on client*/
encrypted_unique_email= aes_256_ctr_encrypt(plain_pw);
encrypted_email=encrypt(user.email);
execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, encrypted_unique_email, encrypted_email, other_stuff) ...
```

This solution however will only work with an empty table, since you likely will not be able to decrypt existing records.

In this case likely your proposal might be the best solution, however you need to lock the users table by `LOCK TABLE users WRITE` and unlock it with `UNLOCK TABLES` to prevent inconsistency.

Comment: From what I've read, LOCK TABLE doesn't work with transactions

Comment: LOCK TABLE works well with transactions. you can even rollback after unlocking.

Comment: "LOCK TABLES implicitly commits the active transaction, if any. Also, starting a transaction always releases all table locks acquired with LOCK TABLES." https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lock-tables/

Comment: Also, I use Galera, and acc. to the docs LOCK TABLES doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another column and use it to store some one-to-one, collision free unrecoverable projection from email to some comparable output. Take any asymmetric cryptographic algorithm, generate public-private key pair, then destroy the private key and store the public key to encrypt the e-mail. The way asymmetric crytography works, it'll be impossible to recover private key even if the attacker gets their hands on public key you are using to encrypt the emails.

Note, however, that this approach has the same vulnerability as storing un-salted hashes: if the attacker gets his hands on your entire database, public key and algorithm, they can run a brute-force attack using some known e-mail dictionary, and successfully find the matching e-mails in their encrypted form, thus matching accounts fom your system to the actual e-mail. Deciding if that situation is an actual security risk is up to you and your ITSec department; but I think it shouldn't be, since you seem to have `decrypt` function available, so if attacker already has access to the database AND the system innards they can just decrypt the stored e-mails.

You can take it one step further and store these encrypted e-mails in a separate table *without* any relation to users. When a new row is inserted to `users`, make sure that a row is inserted into that table as well. Combined with unique index and a transaction, this will ensure no duplicates; however, managing changes and deletions will get more cumbersome. The potential attacker will get literally nothing besides knowing that yes, some of his known e-mails are registered in the system.

Otherwise, you just have to make sure the writes to `users` table are always serialized on the software layer before DB. Write a microservice that queues user storage requests and forbid modification of `users` by any other means.